# How to postpone consuming of messages in spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm working on an application using Spring Integration 5.0.1 and Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1

Currently, the application responds to the `ApplicationReadyEvent` and runs some initialization code that might take a while to finish. This uses none of the spring integration components.

I also have some pretty basic integration flows, written using java dsl and declared as beans in a configuration.

Is there any way to postpone when the flows will start consuming messages? I want to be able to start them manually when the initialization is finished.

It seems that configuring a `ControlBus` would be the solution, but I have no idea how to connect something like that with the other flows.

The following is a sample of how the flow consumes messages :

```
IntegrationFlows.from(sourceGateway)
                .transform(Transformers.fromJson(IncomingTask.class, jsonObjectMapper))

                .handle(IncomingTask.class, (incomingTask, headers) -> {

                //stuff with the task here.

                })

                .get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, you definitely can use `ControlBus` on the matter. With Java DSL it looks like:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow controlBus() {
    return IntegrationFlowDefinition::controlBus;
}
```

To use it you need this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("controlBus.input")
private MessageChannel controlBusChannel;
```

Now we need to know how your target `IntegraionFlow` starts. What consumes messages. For example I have this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileFlow1() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("fileFlow1Input")
            .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(tmpDir.getRoot()),
                        c -> c.id("fileWriting").autoStartup(false))
                .get();
    }
```

Pay attention to the `c.id("fileWriting").autoStartup(false)`. The `id` is for the endpoint bean which can be accessed via command sent to the Control Bus.
The `autoStartup(false)` means that it isn't going to consume messages immediately, but only when we call `start()`. And I do it like this:

```
this.controlBusChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@fileWriting.start()"));
```

Something similar you should ensure in your configuration to postpone messages consumption to the time you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please check the initial question for the code block of the way my flow consumes messages.

Comment: Would you mind showing that `sourceGateway`? What is that and do you configure it?

Comment: For production, its an Amqp inbound gateway with nothing special configured, just a connection factory and queue. For unit testing, its a simple implementation of MessagingGatewaySupport. Obviously I'm interested for the production case. Unit tests can be adjusted.

Comment: Right, so that `AmqpInboundGateway extends AbstractEndpoint` and you really can use its `setAutoStartup(false)`. And I guess this one is a bean anyway and has some particular `id`. So, exactly this `id` you should use in the mentioned above Control Bus command.